# MaterialApp Builder customization for Specific Page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below Flutter main method to show different screens based on the user login status.

```
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
        double paddingBottom = 50.0;
        double paddingRight = 0.0;
        
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            child: widget,
            padding:
                new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: paddingBottom, right: paddingRight),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

The Scaffold has been added with a padding to display AdMob ads and it works fine without any issues on all pages.

But I do not want the ads to be displayed in the login page and it should be full screen without any padding.

How the builder method of MaterialApp to be modified to achieve this?

Comment: You can return `FutureBuilder` instead of `Scaffold`. And inside it check user's loging status. And according to the results return log in screen or main screen (or splash screen)

Comment: Thanks. The exact steps that you mention happens in the State class of MyApp stateful widget. I did it to keep the main.dart file simple as provided in my question. Are there any other ways?

Comment: I doubt it. Or you can put checking into splash screen. And inside splash screen choose which screen have to be loaded next

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FirebaseAuth then in you main function check if your user is logged in by the function `await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` and then pass the user state to your app class. If the user is not `null` then show the ads else not.

**Note:** I am telling to do it in `main` function as it can be turned to `async`.